# Auto Populate CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can I auto populate a CTE to contain the first day of every month
Eg:

1-1-2010
2-1-2010
3-1-2010
4-1-2010

and so on. I looking for a query to do so, rather than using UNION operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at something like

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '01 Jan 2010',
        @EndDate = '01 Jan 2011'

;WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT  @StartDate StartOfMonth
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month,1,StartOfMonth) StartOfMonth
        FROM    Dates
        WHERE   DATEADD(month,1,StartOfMonth) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Dates
```

OUTPUT

```
StartOfMonth
-----------------------
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000
2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
2010-03-01 00:00:00.000
2010-04-01 00:00:00.000
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
2010-07-01 00:00:00.000
2010-08-01 00:00:00.000
2010-09-01 00:00:00.000
2010-10-01 00:00:00.000
2010-11-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

**EDIT**

With column name supplied

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '01 Jan 2010',
        @EndDate = '01 Jan 2011'

;WITH Dates (dt) AS (
        SELECT  @StartDate dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month,1,dt) dt
        FROM    Dates
        WHERE   DATEADD(month,1,dt) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Dates
```

Comment: how would I change the query if my CTE took a param like ;WITH Dates(dt)

Comment: What do you mean *if my CTE took a param like ;WITH Dates(dt)*? Are you refering to **column_name** from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx *WITH expression_name [ ( column_name [,...n] ) ]*

Comment: yes I am sorry..it is a column name i refer to. How will i change query if CTE were to take column name called dt

Comment: Instead of a virtual +10, you should accept the answer that was given to you. It does what you asked for.

Comment: i want to keep the StartOfMonth as you had declared previously and add dt as a column to CTE. I am using this column from a query outside the CTE. How's that possible?

Comment: Wehn i do WITH Dates(dt), query does not compile. says invalid column StartOfMonth. I am ok to use both columns, but then it gives some other error

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTEDates AS
(
SELECT CAST('20100101' AS DATETIME) AS DateVal
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(mm, 1, DateVal)
FROM CTEDates
WHERE DateVal < '20101201'
)

SELECT * FROM CTEDates
```